# How to use Angular 9 and NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR?

Tags: angular, components

I'm trying to create a custom input element but for what reason ever it wont work and doesn't show anything. The question now is: why and what I'm doing wrong?

This is my code:

```js
    import { Component, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
    import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'custom-input',
      template: '<input [(ngModel)]="value"/>local: {{val}}',
      providers: [
        {
          provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
          useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomInputComponent),
          multi: true
        }
      ]
    })
    export class CustomInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
    
      constructor() { }
    
      onChange: any = () => {}
      onTouch: any = () => {}
      val= ""
    
      set value(val){
        if( val !== undefined && this.val !== val){
        this.val = val
        this.onChange(val)
        this.onTouch(val)
        }
       
      }
    
      writeValue(value: any){
        this.value = value
      }
    
      registerOnChange(fn: any){
        this.onChange = fn
      }
    
      registerOnTouched(fn: any){
        this.onTouch = fn
      }
    
    }
```

The HTML looks like:

```html
<custom-input [(ngModel)]="running" name="externalVal" ngDefaultControl> </custom-input>
```

I'm using `ngDefaultControl` because I want use it outside of a form. The problem is now, that the compilation works fine but nothing is shown. Is there any mistake or error in the code?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because 
a) the OP already answered his own question (forgot to close?)
b) the question may not be answered by others without the answer provided by the OP

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I was too stupid, because I forgot to export the component in my shared module where I load the CustomInputModule. Lost two hours of lifetime for such a stupid mistake...